# Plotly with R ggplot privacy

Tags: r, ggplot2, private, plotly

I'm plotting a graph with ggplot, using plotly. How do I make the plot **private** rather than **public** on plotly? My code looks like:

```
a <- ggplot(data, aes(var1, var2, text=var3)) + geom_point()
py$ggplotly(a)
```

Comment: I was looking just today at this page https://plot.ly/r/privacy/ maybe it answer your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to pass the following argument when calling `ggplotly`:

```
py$ggplotly(a, kwargs=list(world_readable=FALSE))
```

For future reference, this is documented here https://plot.ly/r/privacy/

Comment: also, it is logic to add `%>% config(displayModeBar = F)` otherwise your datapoints are easily visible with the plotly modebar